# Can I extract complete dates from file with grep command?

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep, xml

I need help using grep to extract a zoned date time from a file on a Linux system.

Source file is a XML with the data below:

```
<item start="20231010073000 +0100" stop="20231010100000 +0100">...</item>
```

And I need to extract the complete start date, but with grep I can't get it as a complete result. My code:

```
for startDate in $(grep -Eo 'start="[0-9]{14} [\+|\-][0-9]{4}"' "$filepath" ); do
  echo "$startDate"
done
```

And I get it in two different results:

```
start="20231010073000
+0100"
```

Can I get it as bellow:

```
start="20231010073000 +0100"
```

I've tried with `\s`, `[[:space:]]`, and other examples, but with the same solution.

It seems an error in my code but I can't fix it!

I am thankful for any kind of help!!!

Comment: Do you want the date only, or do you really want `start=` as well?

Comment: You might also fix the `[\+|\-]` to a cleaner `[+-]` - the escape backslashes are not necessary within `[]`, and you don't want to match the vertical bar.

Comment: Technically it seems that you want an XML `item`, dates look like so: https://www.educba.com/xml-date/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in your loop: it will, by default, split on `$IFS` (so, with the default value of `$IFS`: any sequence of `space`, `tab`, or `newline` characters, and it will also discard the first and last ones)

There are many ways to fix this, for example:

```
while IFS= read -r StartDate; do
    echo "$StartDate"
done < <(grep -Eo -- 'start="[0-9]{14} [+-][0-9]{4}"' "$filepath")
```

(I use the:  `loop < <( command generating the input )` form instead of `command generating the input | loop` form: so that the loop is in the current shell and not in a subshell as would be the case with the bash shell when the `lastpipe` option is not enabled. This is not always necessary, but is useful to know for example if you want to see the latest value of `$StartDate` after the loop: if in a subshell, the value will have disappeared at the end of the subshell and can't be retrieved in the current shell.)

Comment: Ok! I understand, the grep is working ok, but the loop separates results! Thanks!!

Comment: Please, stop using `grep` to parse `XML` (-1)

Comment: It's our role to guide beginners in the right direction. Even if OP asked `grep`, it's not the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

[Don't use `grep` nor `regex` to parse `HTML/XML`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49352373/465183) you cannot, must not parse any structured text like XML/HTML with tools designed to process raw text lines. If you need to process XML/HTML, use an XML/HTML parser. A great majority of languages have built-in support for parsing XML and there are dedicated tools like `xidel`, `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint` if you need a quick shot from a command line shell... Never accept a job if you don't have access to proper tools.

---

The most advanced command line tools around is [`xidel`](https://github.com/benibela/xidel). The syntax is much more intuitive/modern (and do support `XPath3` where other tools are stuck with limited `XPath1`), than `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint`, see:

```
xidel -e '//item/@start' -s file.xml
20231010073000 +0100
```

- `-e` for `XPath` `e`xpression
- `-s` for `s`ilent (no status informations)

The query language is `XPath` and it's very useful in many cases to parse XML/HTML.

---

`XPath` tutorials:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp
http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xpath/info
https://topswagcode.com/xpath/ (interactive `XPath` game, when you have the basics and want to practice interactively)

Answer (score 4):

Since you are dealing with XML, we should really be using an XML parser to get the attribute's value.

The following shows how to get the `start` attribute's value from any `item` node in the entire document using `xmlstarlet`:

```bash
$ xmlstarlet select --template --value-of '//item/@start' --nl file
20231010073000 +0100
```

Or, using abbreviated option names:

```bash
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//item/@start' -n file
20231010073000 +0100
```

If there are several `item` nodes, and you only want the value from the `start` attribute of the first one, use `//item[1]/@start` in the XPath query.

You may then transfer the result into a variable with a standard command substitution:

```bash
start=$( xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//item[1]/@start' file )
```

(I dropped the `-n` option from the above command as it's no longer needed.  It adds a newline character to the end of the output, but the command substitution would remove it.)

Or, you can read them all into a `bash` array with `readarray`:

```bash
readarray -t startarray < <(
    xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//item/@start' -n file
)
```

and then loop over it (`for start in "${startarray[@]}"; do ...; done`) or loop over the output of `xmlstarlet` directly:

```bash
while IFS= read -r start; do
   # ...
done < <( xmlstarlet ...as above... )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot install extra dependences on the system to properly parse the XML, then I would write a script that handles the parsing a bit more elegantly and not trying to do it on one line.

Here is an example script of me parsing those out those times from the line your provided.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

INPUT_FILE="$1"
TIME_FILTER='[0-9]*\s(\+|\-)[0-9]*'

__getStart(){
  line="$1"
  echo "$line" | egrep -o "start=\"${TIME_FILTER}\"" | egrep -o "$TIME_FILTER"
}

__getStop(){
  line="$1"
  echo "$line" | egrep -o "stop=\"${TIME_FILTER}\""  | egrep -o "$TIME_FILTER"
}
  

while IFS= read -r line; do
    start_time="$(__getStart "$line")"
    stop_time="$(__getStop "$line")"
    echo "Start Time: ${start_time}"
    echo "Stop Time: ${stop_time}"
done < "$INPUT_FILE"
```

You can use the script in this fashion

```
[/var/tmp] $ ./get-dates.sh date-extraction.xml 
Start Time: 20231010073000 +0100
Stop Time: 20231010100000 +0100
```

Comment: Please note this is a rough example of filtering, there will need to be more massaging of the data. For instance, if the line doesn't include start/stop, my example will print empty values for the lines "Start Time:*" and "End Time:*"

If the start/end times are always in the header of the file, then you can greatly reduce the search. But as others have mentioned it's more ideal to harness an XML parser to properly achieve what you want to do with a great degree of confidence.

Comment: If instead of reading every line and then calling grep line by line, you first call grep on the whole file and then read greps output line by line (e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/756935/133219) your script would run much faster since given, for example, a 1000 line input file it'd spawn 1 process to call grep instead of spawning 1000 processes.

Comment: By the way, `egrep` was deprecated almost 20 years ago in favor of `grep -E`.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton. I'm not sure _why_ I used `egrep` in this example. I never use it in my actual work. Thanks for sharing the line-by-line grep. That's going to be useful in the future!